# simple search in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array with the following values

```
 - Array ( [id] => 3 [parent_id] => 2 [name] => Fitness ) 
 - Array ( [id] => 4 [parent_id] => 3 [name] => Why do it) 
 - Array ( [id] => 5 [parent_id] => 3 [name] => Nutrition)
```

Id like to query it along the lines of

```
array_search([parent_id]='3', $array)
```

and return a list of matching elements. (In this instance it would be id's 4 & 5). I'm not sure if `array_search()` is the right way to go about this. May attempts are failing at moment.

Comment: Perhaps you can share your attempts with us?

Comment: Are you only wanting to search for parent_id or is it a given field?

Comment: If you're trying to build tree structure, there may already be questions about that.

Comment: thank you for the nudge! ... I'm searching on this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function mySearchArr($key, $value, $myBigArr) {
  $searchArr = array();
  foreach($myBigArr as $smallArr)
    if($smallArr[$key] == $value)
      $searchArr[] = $smallArr;
  return $searchArr
}

$matches = mySearchArr('parent_id', 3, $array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a custom callback

```
$lookup_id = 3;
$results = array_filter($your_array, function($arr) use ($lookup_id) {

return $your_array['parent_id'] == $lookup_id;

});
```

This code requires i believe >=PHP5.3, if you have an older version, you will have to implement the callback using either an actual defined function (normal php function), or using `create_function`